# Post Form with Session to iframe without reloading page?

Tags: php, html, session-variables

Here's what I'm trying to do (without reloading the page):

1. Make a Form
2. Submit it and open iframe(iframe.php)
3. Put values of inputs into variables
4. Put variables into Session
5. Pass session variables to ajax.php
6. make an ajax request from iframe.php to ajax.php
7. Meanwhile show loading gif
8. display result of the ajax call in the iframe
9. hide loading gif.

My only problem is, I don't know how to submit the form without reloading the page, so I can pass the values into variables and then into session.

This is my shorted code:

#### MainPage.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['Flightnumber1'] = $_POST['Flightnumber1'];
        $_SESSION['Datetime1'] = $_POST['Datetime1'];
    }
?>
<form target="iframe" method="post" action="iframe.html">
    <input id="Flightnumber1" name="Flightnumber1" type="text" />
    <input id="Datetime1" name="Datetime1"  type="text"/>
    <input id="Submit-Prufbox" name="Submit" type="submit" onclick='document.getElementById("iframe").src="iframe.php"; $("#iframe").show();' />
</form>
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

#### iframe.php:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
 ?>

    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div style="display: none;" id="cover" style="position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0; left: 0; background: #FFFFFF; z-index:99999; font-size: 60px; text-align: center; padding-top: 200px; color: #247AFC; user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-o-user-select: none;"><img src="PageImages/loading.gif" /><br />Flug wird gepr&uuml;ft</div>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#php').load('Rechner.php', function() {
                            $("#cover").fadeOut(1500);
                        });
                    });
                </script>
    <div id="php"></div>
```

#### ajax.php:

```
<php 
    session_start();
    echo $regValue = $_SESSION['Flightnumber1'];
    echo $regValue2 = $_SESSION['Datetime1'];
?>
```

I hope someone understands that mess, but I really have no idea how to explain that more ordinary as it is really complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use jQuery.

Submit the form with ajax using `jQuery.post()`.

Here is a documentation and an example: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/